# Performance problem with the Symfony Serializer

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I need some help on a performance issue concerning the native Symfony Serializer

If I try to serialize an entity array like this :

```
$serializedReservations = $this->serializer->serialize($reservations, 'json', ['groups' => 'reservationDetails', 'enable_max_depth' => true]);
```

The serialization take more than 1s

On the other hand, if I do :

```
$data = [];
foreach ($reservations as $reservation){
    $data['idreservation'] = $reservation->getIdreservation();
    $data['idcommand'] = $reservation->getCommand()->getIdCommand();
    $data['title'] =$reservation->getCommand()->getTitle();
    $data['serialnumber'] = $reservation->getStock()->getSerialNumber();
    $data['ubd'] = $reservation->getStock()->getUBD();
}

$serializedReservations = $this->serializer->serialize($data, 'json', ['groups' => 'reservationDetails', 'enable_max_depth' => true]);
```

Serialization only take 21 ms !

So of course it's faster to serialize an array than an entity, but why is the 1st method so slow when it contains exactly the same datas (the "reservationDetails" group filter the same 6 data I get from the data[]) ?

If someone has an idea or even a lead, I'm interested. If I can't fix the problem I might try to switch to JmsSerializer.

Comment: The answer is really simple - it does not actually contain the same data. The entity contains a lot more. It contains lazy loaded data for all related entities and it's accessible from it. When serializing you don't see it because it's dumbed down to an array. But the entity object itself is much larger. To avoid this performance drop simple write your own query in the repository which gets only the data you need in an array.

Comment: The lazy loading also appen when i do a getStock() and a getCommand() in the second case so i don't see where is the big difference. 
Also Command and Stock are not collections, they are ManyToOne relations so only 2 entity should be loaded. I don't think it totally explain the big time difference.

Edit : Exept if the serializer lazy load relations who are not in the Serialization group ? But this sound useless.

Comment: Yes, logically it shouldn't but it does. That is why I always use custom functions in my repositories so I don't return whole entities.

Comment: I already use custom function in my repository and i use the same function on the two methods.
Also, i already use getCommand() and getSock on the same entity before in another function so the entity should be already hydrated.

Comment: I checked with the debugger and only the Command and Stock entities are lazy loaded in the first case.